# Video preview issue in LibVlc2.1.12

Tags: android

How to set videoView in center.Please refer attached screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Please check xml
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

Comment: post your layout xml file also

Comment: Thanks Sudheesh . Please check xml image

Comment: change your framelayout's width and height to wrap content and centerinparent to true

Comment: Please check updated xml image. but it is not working getting same preview.

Comment: its working perfectly, i'm tested it now

Comment: whats your framelayout's context actually referring ?

Comment: you should check whether that playvideoactivity possess any layout configuration and change it to above said wrap content and centerinparent to true

Comment: tools:context="com.groupgallery.iptv.activities.PlayVideoActivity". So you playing video using LibVlc?      Please try for given Link   https://devlopmentthegroup.s3.amazonaws.com/20170827020006trailer.mp4

Comment: is this com.groupgallery.iptv.activities.PlayVideoAct‌​ivity is your activity ? or any 3rd party?

Comment: Yes it is my activity.

Comment: is there any layout parameters set for your video layout?

Comment: No, I haven't set any layout params.

Comment: then it should be working by now. check again, clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Tried for given link devlopmentthegroup.s3.amazonaws.com/20170827020006trailer.mp‌​4 ? can you please attach screenshot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override method `onNewVideoLayout(IVLCVout vlcVout, int width, int height, int visibleWidth, int visibleHeight, int sarNum, int sarDen)`.

I found the above info from [VLC Android Gitlab](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/issues/278) while researching for your issue.

Actually your code doesn't providing the proper **width** and **height** for the video that is showing in your `surfaceview`, so it always goes to some default position.

Hope it helps you...